# Android Screen Turns Black

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am looking for any reason this could be happening.  I am currently writing an image-stitching app for Android.  I have decided to use OpenCV4Android and I also had to do some Android NDK stuff in order to get it to work (I am almost sure this is somehow causing my problem).  The problem I am having now is that when my code reaches the OpenCV NDK portion of the program, the screen on the Android device turns black and the logcat stops displaying anything.  Like it crashes without telling me of any errors at all.  This is very unusual because even in the .cpp portion of the project if there is a problem, the logcat would at least display something vague like **Fatal Signal 11** and then end.

Because of this, I have no idea where to begin searching for a solution.  I am also a beginner when it comes to Android programming, so it may be something than can be easily overlooked by a beginner. Any help is appreciated!

More info on the blank screen:

- Android device is not frozen, I can exit the app
- If I try to enter the app again through the multitasking button, it takes about 5 seconds to enter
- logcat or Android Studio is not frozen

EDIT: After just leaving the black screen on the Android device it finally said [App Name] wasn't responding, and gave me the option to either close it, or keep waiting.  My suspicion is that this line

```
Mat img = imread("/storage/emulated/0/AppName/test" + id + ".jpg");
```

in the .cpp portion of the project is causing this behavior, but I am not sure.  I omitted the line and the app ran as it should have.  After using that line again, it broke, but after omitting it a second time the app kept the black screen behavior.

EDIT EDIT: Here is the logcat with no filters selected (apologies for the wall of text):

04-19 14:23:16.943 14240-14240/aaron.picstitch D/in stitchImages: BEGIN
04-19 14:23:16.943 14240-14240/aaron.picstitch D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/aaron.picstitch-183/libMyLibrary.so 0x41f7ba28
04-19 14:23:16.943 14240-14240/aaron.picstitch D/dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/app-lib/aaron.picstitch-183/libMyLibrary.so 0x41f7ba28
04-19 14:23:16.943 14240-14240/aaron.picstitch D/dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/aaron.picstitch-183/libMyLibrary.so 0x41f7ba28, skipping init
04-19 14:23:18.114 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.7
04-19 14:23:19.946 763-978/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:19.946 763-978/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:19.956 144-198/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=159 Removed FxternalPic (10/14)
04-19 14:23:19.956 144-703/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=159 Removed FxternalPic (-2/14)
04-19 14:23:19.956 763-976/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:19.956 763-976/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:19.966 763-777/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:19.966 763-777/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:19.966 144-3490/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=160 Removed FxternalPic (11/13)
04-19 14:23:19.966 144-198/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=160 Removed FxternalPic (-2/13)
04-19 14:23:19.976 763-978/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:19.976 763-978/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:19.986 763-1308/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:19.986 763-1308/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:20.286 763-978/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:20.286 763-978/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:20.286 144-1100/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=158 Removed QickerActiv (10/12)
04-19 14:23:20.286 144-196/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=158 Removed QickerActiv (-2/12)
04-19 14:23:20.286 763-777/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
04-19 14:23:20.296 763-777/? I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: visibility is same
04-19 14:23:20.296 144-144/? W/SurfaceFlinger: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
04-19 14:23:21.627 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:23.449 563-3587/? D/BatteryService: level:90, scale:100, status:3, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4209, temperature: 270, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303544, invalid charger:0, online:4, current avg:0, charge type:1, power sharing:false
04-19 14:23:23.449 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
04-19 14:23:23.449 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
04-19 14:23:23.449 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: [update] mShowingCMASText is false
04-19 14:23:23.449 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: CMASIcon was GONE : 
04-19 14:23:23.449 563-563/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
04-19 14:23:23.449 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
04-19 14:23:23.469 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(544), More:false, Req:false Child:3
04-19 14:23:23.479 763-763/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:90 status:3 health:2
04-19 14:23:24.570 563-1583/? D/SSRMv2:SIOP: SIOP:: AP = 310, Delta = 10
04-19 14:23:24.620 563-683/? W/ActivityManager: Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-19 14:23:25.151 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:28.654 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:32.177 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.1 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:32.448 563-868/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 115
04-19 14:23:34.590 563-1583/? D/SSRMv2:SIOP: SIOP:: AP = 310, Delta = 0
04-19 14:23:35.681 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:39.184 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:42.698 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:43.448 563-3489/? D/BatteryService: level:90, scale:100, status:3, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4206, temperature: 280, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303544, invalid charger:0, online:4, current avg:0, charge type:1, power sharing:false
04-19 14:23:43.448 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
04-19 14:23:43.448 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
04-19 14:23:43.448 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: [update] mShowingCMASText is false
04-19 14:23:43.448 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: CMASIcon was GONE : 
04-19 14:23:43.448 563-563/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
04-19 14:23:43.458 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
04-19 14:23:43.468 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(544), More:false, Req:false Child:3
04-19 14:23:43.479 763-763/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:90 status:3 health:2
04-19 14:23:44.600 563-1583/? D/SSRMv2:SIOP: SIOP:: AP = 300, Delta = -10
04-19 14:23:46.191 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:49.695 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:53.218 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:53.448 563-2198/? D/BatteryService: level:90, scale:100, status:3, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4209, temperature: 290, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303544, invalid charger:0, online:4, current avg:0, charge type:1, power sharing:false
04-19 14:23:53.448 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
04-19 14:23:53.448 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleBatteryUpdate
04-19 14:23:53.448 563-563/? D/BatteryService: Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
04-19 14:23:53.458 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: [update] mShowingCMASText is false
04-19 14:23:53.458 763-763/? D/CMASMessage: CMASIcon was GONE : 
04-19 14:23:53.458 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-PhoneStatusBar:  mBrightnessEnablebySettings = true mBrightnessEnablebyBattery = true mBrightnessEnablebyDisableFlag = true mPmsBrightnessEnablebySettings = true
04-19 14:23:53.458 763-763/? D/BatteryMeterView: ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED : level:90 status:3 health:2
04-19 14:23:53.468 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(544), More:false, Req:false Child:3
04-19 14:23:54.609 563-1583/? D/SSRMv2:SIOP: SIOP:: AP = 310, Delta = 10
04-19 14:23:56.721 563-681/? D/SensorService:   -0.2 0.2 9.8
04-19 14:23:59.985 563-698/? V/AlarmManager: waitForAlarm result :8
04-19 14:23:59.995 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
04-19 14:23:59.995 763-763/? D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor: handleTimeUpdate
04-19 14:23:59.995 563-563/? V/AlarmManager: ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
04-19 14:24:00.015 763-763/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger: checkOverflow(544), More:false, Req:false Child:3
04-19 14:24:00.035 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> WCS:175 [0:0] action : androidintentactionTIME_TICK
04-19 14:24:00.045 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> WC:41 [0:0] action : actionTIME_TICK
04-19 14:24:00.045 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> WC:55 [0:0] settings CT : androidappReceiverRestrictedContext@41f8d0e0
04-19 14:24:00.045 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIM:146 [0:0] setContext
04-19 14:24:00.055 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> UIM:371 [0:0] isUpdateWidget -> false
04-19 14:24:00.065 1606-1606/? D/accuweather: [AccuTab_Magagine]>>> SEM:742 [0:0] isShowNextEvent -> false

Comment: What is the filtering on logcat set to? There is likely a stack trace accompanying the fatal signal error, but you won't be able to see it unless you select 'No Filters' for logcat.

Comment: @bullsy I have edited the post with the logcat set to no filter.  I output "BEGIN" right before it calls the .cpp portion.

Comment: I misunderstood your question - I thought you were seeing a crash but no error messages. If the app is really crashing, a popup with the text 'YourAppName has stopped' will show up on the device. If you're not seeing that popup, the app is still running, but it's getting stuck. What do you do right after printing 'BEGIN'?